# Configuring symfony for using eaccelerator

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, eaccelerator

Is there any configuration for improving performance of symfony2 by eaccelerator?
And so is there any configuration for using eaccelerator to take advantage of doctrine "Query Cache,Result Cache,Metadata Cache"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely possible to use eAccelerator with Symfony2 and Doctrine, however there are issues you would need to resolve:

1. [Eaccelerator strips doc blocks by default, making Symfony/Doctrine pretty much non functional](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/eaccelerator-and-doctrine-2)
2. To see valuable performance gains with Symfony2 you would need to create an eAccelerator [ClassLoader](https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader). You'll find most of the overhead in Symfony comes from file_exists calls in the autoloader if you don't optimize the composer autoload dump using `--optimize` (at least I do).